# Why go inserts extra assembly code for type conversion?

Tags: assembly, go, type-conversion

I expected that type conversion in golang is just to get the code compiled and nothing happens at the runtime. But the following type conversion in golang generates some assembly code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type mystring string

type MyString interface {
    get() string
}

func (self mystring) get() string {
    return string(self)
}

func main() {
    x := newDString("hai")
    str := convertToString(x)
    fmt.Println("Ans:  ", str)
}

func newDString(str string) MyString {
    return mystring(str)
}

func convertToString(input MyString) string {
    return string(input.(mystring))
}
```

In the above code, I have a new type `mystring` which is just an another name of the built-in type `string`. I expected that only the compiler uses this information and nothing gets passed to runtime. I mean, I expected that converting `mystring` to `string` (and vice versa) must take **no processor cycles**. But when I did `go build -gcflags -S delete.go > test.s` on my code, I see the following assembly code involved in the type conversion. What do these assembly codes do?

```
"".convertToString t=1 size=122 args=0x20 locals=0x20
    0x0000 00000 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:27)  TEXT    "".convertToString(SB), $32-32
    0x0000 00000 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:27)  MOVQ    (TLS), CX
    0x0009 00009 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:27)  CMPQ    SP, 16(CX)
    0x000d 00013 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:27)  JLS 115
    0x000f 00015 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:27)  SUBQ    $32, SP
    0x0013 00019 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:27)  MOVQ    BP, 24(SP)
    0x0018 00024 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:27)  LEAQ    24(SP), BP
    0x001d 00029 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:27)  FUNCDATA    $0, gclocals·c55e845a0a62e9baae6c740db5a20866(SB)
    0x001d 00029 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:27)  FUNCDATA    $1, gclocals·69c1753bd5f81501d95132d08af04464(SB)
    0x001d 00029 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  MOVQ    "".input+40(FP), AX
    0x0022 00034 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  TESTQ   AX, AX
    0x0025 00037 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  JEQ $0, 43
    0x0027 00039 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  MOVQ    8(AX), AX
    0x002b 00043 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:27)  LEAQ    type."".mystring(SB), CX
    0x0032 00050 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  CMPQ    CX, AX
    0x0035 00053 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  JNE $0, 87
    0x0037 00055 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  MOVQ    "".input+48(FP), AX
    0x003c 00060 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  MOVQ    (AX), CX
    0x003f 00063 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  MOVQ    8(AX), AX
    0x0043 00067 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  MOVQ    CX, "".~r1+56(FP)
    0x0048 00072 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  MOVQ    AX, "".~r1+64(FP)
    0x004d 00077 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  MOVQ    24(SP), BP
    0x0052 00082 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  ADDQ    $32, SP
    0x0056 00086 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  RET
    0x0057 00087 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  MOVQ    AX, (SP)
    0x005b 00091 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  MOVQ    CX, 8(SP)
    0x0060 00096 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  LEAQ    type."".MyString(SB), AX
    0x0067 00103 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  MOVQ    AX, 16(SP)
    0x006c 00108 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  PCDATA  $0, $1
    0x006c 00108 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  CALL    runtime.panicdottype(SB)
    0x0071 00113 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  UNDEF
    0x0073 00115 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:28)  NOP
    0x0073 00115 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:27)  PCDATA  $0, $-1
    0x0073 00115 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:27)  CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
    0x0078 00120 (/Users/deepak-3207/delete.go:27)  JMP 0
```

Comment: I would guess those instructions are for the type assertion, not the conversion.

Comment: @MiloChristiansen I guess you are correct. string() doesn't do any work...It is input.(mystring) which takes some instructions

Comment: Not even @MiloChristiansen is correct, but there's more to this: a value of an interface type is a struct of two pointers: one to the underlying value implementing that interface, and another one -- to the type info object describing the (real) type of that value. So the type conversions to/from an interface type to a concrete type naturally require a) type checking at run time, b) copying data around.

Comment: @kostix I guess you are talking about something like string(v) where v is a variable of type interface{}. But this won't even compile, right?

Comment: Re. "won't compile" -- yes, it won't. Re. my whole comment, no: I were describing precisely the case of a type assertion like `input.(mystring)`. Type conversion from `mystring` to `string` should indeed not require CPU cycles at runtime.